# How to do a hidden html <div> visable with a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying to do a hidden **HTML** `<div>` visible, by running a JavaScript function.

This is the hidden `div` I want to get visable with a JavaScript function:

```
<div id="Signup" class="modal hide fade LoginSignup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true"> 
    Some content* 
</div>
```

Right now I'm using this button to show the hidden `div` content:

```
<li>
    <a href="#Signup" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success">Sign Up</a>
</li>
```

Is this the best way to do it? Or is it an other way to get a designable pop up window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also try out jQuery toggle

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

CSS to control it:

```
#Signup{
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;/*IE*/
  display: none;
}
```

or

```
#Signup{
  position:absolute;
  left:-1000px;/*top:-1000px;*/
```

}

use JavaScript to change the values.

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I do for JQuery

**HIDE**

```
$("#hidden_content").hide("fast");
```

**SHOW**

```
("#default").show("fast");
```

And then if I want it to be hidden from the start I use CSS as follows

```
#hidden_content
{
    display:none;
}
```